# FB Post in the Feed of a Group

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have the following PHP code to post in a Facebook Group Feed where the the publisher is admin of. The code is as follows:

```
$post_array=array ('link'=>$link_share,'message' => $message);
try {
  $response = $fb->post(
    "/{$group_id}" . "/feed",
    $post_array,
    "{$access_token}"
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

But when I execute it I get the error:

Graph returned an error: Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'group_id' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

I read all the documentation, the user has the permissions to publish in the group but I keep getting that error. Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#groups-4-4

Comment: I am having the same problem! I've read the change log as well and I have granted myself 'user_managed_groups'. I am the owner of this app and just need it to post to my group. I thought app owners do not need approval to post on their pages / groups?!

Comment: It also says "We are not reviewing apps at this time due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform." How awesome Facebook! Platform abuse by posting to my group from the Cambridge Analytica breach? They don't correlate.

Comment: I am still having trouble with this. I am now trying to submit my app for approval. It even says right on the top "You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or by a reduced number of people. Any account listed in the Roles tab in your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers and testers, can access all permissions and generate a user or page access token."

I am listed under the Roles for my app, but it still does not work. I can't even do a simple get request to my group id.